# Probabilities/Odds

Tags: probability

I am wondering about the probability of this happening:

> There are 3 unique objects in a total 55 objects. As a consequence, picking one from the 3 objects is a 3 in 55 chance.

> What I do not know how to figure out is: If you pick 52 of the 55 objects, what are the odds that the 3 objects remaining are the 3 unique objects ?

Comment: Are you picking them with or without replacement?

Answer (score 0):

The probability of picking those objects is identical to the probability of **not** picking them:

$$\frac{1}{\binom{55}{3}}=\frac{1}{\binom{55}{52}}=\frac{1}{26235}$$